# win7 and win xp roaming profile

Tags: windows-7, samba, roaming-profile, user-profile

I have a samba server with WinXP roaming profiles and now I have to have some win7 clients as well. 
Is there any trick which would allowed to login any users on Winxp and Win7 with the same profile settings?
Settings contains:
- desktop settings
- network drivers
- local setting (no access to control panel etc)

These are working now with WinXP but I could not manage them on Win7. Any link or even a simple example would be really appreciated.

I know this is very brief list but if you need any more I am happy to provide more.

(sorry for my English)

every trick or possible solution would make me happy:)))

Finally I have some half result, with KIXSTART and disable UAC in Win7. Now I can map drivers from SMB but the profile is still an issue. I think I open an other question just focusing Win7 profile and will play around/merge the profiles.:) Thanks for all the comments.

Comment: Regarding your flag. Just open another question. Reference this question if it will help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the profile format is different between Windows XP and Windows 7; you can't use a roaming profile between these two systems, even on a native Active Directory domain.

More info here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766489(WS.10).aspx.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. Is there any solution for this issue?

Comment: As I said, unfortunately not.

Comment: @AndrasSebestyen this isn't an "issue", in the sense that "issue" equates to fault, and certainly not an issue with Samba. Microsoft made a design decision that the profile structure for windows vista onwards would work differently to the previous method, and that as such they'd have to be kept and managed separately. Its possible to redirect folders so you a user can have one set of home drive areas (e.g. my documents, etc) but they'll always need two actual profiles.

Comment: Thanks very much for the comments. I hoped that as everything else can be programmed as samba now can handle with AD. So I hoped that e.g. KIX can do something like that: ;Get System Type
 $ostype = @PRODUCTTYPE

;Apply windows 7 specific registry edits
IF "@PRODUCTTYPE"="Windows 6.1 / 1"

Comment: I am also happy to create .v2 folder if I could open it from smb... but I haven't found the solution that's why I am here.

Comment: Thanks guys I have now some half solution. I have got WinXp roaming profile and a Win7 profile. But the .V2 folder doesn't come on Win7 yet.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, there are 3rd party products that do allow roaming between operating system versions.

Three examples off the top of my head:

http://www.ressoftware.com/
http://www.appsense.com/
http://immidio.com/flexprofiles/